# Callback query не работаеть телеграм php?

Tags: yii2, telegram-bot, бот

Я использую https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api.

```
public function actionMybigbot(){
            $token = '*************************************************';
            $bot = new Client($token);
            $bot->on(function ($update) use ($bot) {
                $message = $update->getMessage();
                $text = $message->getText();
                $chat_id = $update->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();
                $keyboardQuest = [
                    ['text'=>'1-Савол','callback_data'=>'q1'],
                    ['text'=>'2-Савол','callback_data'=>'q2'],
                    ['text'=>'3-Савол','callback_data'=>'q3'],
                    ['text'=>'4-Савол','callback_data'=>'q4'],
                    ['text'=>'5-Савол','callback_data'=>'q5'],
                ];
                switch ($text){
                    case '/start':
                        $keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\ReplyKeyboardMarkup(array(array("Savollar", "Javoblar")), true,true);
                        $bot->sendMessage($chat_id, 'awdawd',null,false,null,$keyboard);
                    break;
                    case 'Savollar':
                        $keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\Inline\InlineKeyboardMarkup(array($keyboardQuest));
                        $bot->sendMessage($chat_id, 'Savollardan birini tanlang!',null,false,null,$keyboard);
                    break;
                }
            },function($message){ return true;});

            $bot->callbackQuery(function ($callbackQuery) use ($bot) {

                $bot->sendMessage($chat_id, 'Savollardan birini tanlang!');

            });
            $bot->run();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Сначала вы должны получить данные, на которые нажал пользователь. `$callbackQuery->getData()` из которого вы `callback_data` с помощью switch-case.

```py
    $bot->callbackQuery(function ($callbackQuery) use ($bot) {
    switch ($callbackQuery->getData()){
        case 'q1':
            # Дополнение к вопросу 1
            $bot->sendMessage($chat_id, 'Savollardan birini tanlang!');  
        break;
    }
});
```